# Can I reuse an IQueryable<dynamic> .Select() statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using C# and Entity Framework v6.2.0

In a repository class I have this function:

```
public IQueryable<dynamic> GetRelatedCallDetailsAsNoTracking(Guid callThreadId)
    {
        return _context.CallDetails
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(callDetail => callDetail.Callers)
            .Select(callDetail => new
            {
                callDetail.Id,
                callDetail.EnteredByEmail,
                callDetail.CallStartTime,
                callDetail.CallDirectionIsIncoming,
                callDetail.CallThread_Id,
                Children = callDetail.Children.Select(child => new
                {
                    child.FirstName,
                    child.LastName,
                    child.DateOfBirth
                }),
                Callers = callDetail.Callers.Select(y => new
                {
                    y.FirstName,
                    y.LastName,
                    y.PhoneNumber.Number
                }),
                callDetail.SensitiveCall,
                callDetail.SuccessStory
            })
            .Where(x => x.CallThread_Id == callThreadId)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CallStartTime);
    }
```

In the same Repo, I have a second function that has the exact same query with some added `.Where(...)` statements.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
public IQueryable<dynamic> SecondQuery(Guid callThreadId)
{
    return BaseQuery()
        .Where(x => x.CallTherad_Id == callThreadId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x...);
}
public IQueryable<dynamic> SecondQuery(Guid callThreadId, string secondParameter, bool thirdParameter)
{
    return BaseQuery()
        .Where(x => x...)
        .Where(x => x...)
        .Where(x => x...)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x...);
}
```

---

I tried:

```
private IQueryable<dynamic> BaseQuery()
{
    return _context.CallDetails
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(callDetail => callDetail.Callers)
        .Select(callDetail => new
        {
            callDetail.Id,
            callDetail.EnteredByEmail,
            callDetail.CallStartTime,
            callDetail.CallDirectionIsIncoming,
            callDetail.CallThread_Id,
            Children = callDetail.Children.Select(child => new
            {
                child.FirstName,
                child.LastName,
                child.DateOfBirth
            }),
            Callers = callDetail.Callers.Select(y => new
            {
                y.FirstName,
                y.LastName,
                y.PhoneNumber.Number
            }),
            callDetail.SensitiveCall,
            callDetail.SuccessStory
        });
}

public IQueryable<dynamic> GetRelatedCallDetailsAsNoTracking(Guid callThreadId)
{
    return BaseQuery().Where(x => x.CallThread_Id == callThreadId);
}
```

But this gets me the error:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: Why use dynamic here at all?

Comment: Fair point, I suppose I could try to convert it to a strongly typed object before returning it. I have been trying to keep that logic out of my repo if possible.

Comment: a different route you can take is add an Expression parameter to your BaseQuery method and pass in your where conditions

Comment: Inject a "converter class" dependency into your repo, that way you have full control.  Little bit of generics and you have a full customize-able solution.  Or you can use extension methods outside of the class

Comment: @JamieD77 I tried adding `Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>> query` as a parameter to BaseQuery and got the same result when passing in `x => x.CallThread_Id == callThreadId)`

Comment: well you shouldnt use `Func<dynamic` and you dont need to if you're always querying CallDetails. it should be `Func<CallDetails` and the where would be before the `Select`

Comment: @JamieD77 That seems to be working for me, but gets a little trickier when I need to have multiple where conditions passed in one case and not the other. I'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: @RyanTaite build your multiple where conditions into a singe expression whenever possible.. `Where(a => a.1 == p1 && a.2 == p2`) instead of `Where(a => a.1 == p1).Where(a => a.2 == p2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse any part of your query. As a solution to your problem you need to define a non-anonymous type that you can use in your method signature:

```
class CallDetails {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    IQueryable<CallDetailsChild> Children { get; set; }
    IQueryable<CallDetailsCaller> Callers { get; set; }
    //...
}

class CallDetailsChild {
    //...
}

class CallDetailsCaller {
    //...
}

//...

private IQueryable<CallDetails> BaseQuery()
{
    return _context.CallDetails
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(callDetail => callDetail.Callers)
        .Select(callDetail => new CallDetails
        {
            callDetail.Id,
            callDetail.EnteredByEmail,
            callDetail.CallStartTime,
            callDetail.CallDirectionIsIncoming,
            callDetail.CallThread_Id,
            Children = callDetail.Children.Select(child => new CallDetailsChild
            {
                child.FirstName,
                child.LastName,
                child.DateOfBirth
            }),
            Callers = callDetail.Callers.Select(y => new CallDetailsCaller
            {
                y.FirstName,
                y.LastName,
                y.PhoneNumber.Number
            }),
            callDetail.SensitiveCall,
            callDetail.SuccessStory
        });
}
```

This solution is a little verbose, but that's the only option you have if you want to use a custom type instead of an entity type and reuse it like this.

Comment: I actually already have a `CallDetail`, `Child`, and `Caller` class. Looks like I would need to change things like `callDetail.Id` to `Id = callDetail.Id` and so on in your example before it stops yelling at me. Unfortunately it seems EF doesn't like me mapping to Entity Models during the query, and my current project doesn't use DTOs (only Models and ViewModels), so I'd have to build that out first before I can confirm this works.